# Why עשה instead of ברא in Genesis 1:7?

Tags: hebrew, genesis, word-study, creation

> Genesis 1:7
>
> ויעש אלהים את־הרקיע ויבדל בין המים אשר מתחת לרקיע ובין המים אשר מעל לרקיע ויהי־כן׃
>
> And God made the firmament, and divided between the waters which were under the firmament and between the waters which were above the firmament. And it was so.

The word translated in this verse as "created" is ויעש, a form of the verb עשה. The verbs עשה and ברא appear often in the Genesis 1 creation account, and they seem almost interchangable. So, why did the Author use the 3MS vav-consecutive imperfect of עשה instead of the 3MS vav-consecutive of ברא?

**Some observations**

Day 1: Neither עשה nor ברא is used in describing creation of the light, but instead we have *yehi owr wa-yehi owr* ('Light shalt exist.' And light existed.)

Day 2: עשה is used to describe creation of the firmament

Day 3: Neither verb is used for God's creation of plants, but instead the earth "sprouts" (דשא) the vegetation. The verb עשה, however, is used to describe the tree "bearing" fruit (perhaps, in its own way, "creating" fruit?)

Day 4: עשה is used to describe creation of the luminaries

Day 5: ברא is used to describe creation of the sea-animals and sky-animals

Day 6: עשה is used to describe creation of the land-animals. עשה is also used when God says, "Let us create man in our image." But then, we have ברא used 3 times when God says "So God created man in his own image, in the image of God created he him; male and female created he them."

In these observations, however, I fail to see a pattern which might explain the use of עשה on Day 2.

Comment: Are you aware of the current discussion on ברא? I wrote about it here: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/31689/2672

Comment: FYI there is an analysis of the Hebrew of this verse online on the "Daily Dose of Hebrew" website (http://dailydoseofhebrew.com). They send you a new, 2 minute video of Hebrew exposition of a single verse each day and they are great:  https://dailydoseofhebrew.com/scripture-passage/genesis-17/

Comment: There is no order and rigor to your analysis. If there would be one, you'd notice that, for instance, the expression *let there be* (יהי) is by no means confined to the first day.

Comment: Please consider this [article](https://www.academia.edu/34944151/Separation_and_Creation_in_Genesis_1_and_Psalm_104_A_Continuation_of_the_Discussion_of_the_Verb_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90), I think it is a quite on topic.

Answer (score 1):

You have done a very careful analysis.

*bara* does not mean "create out of nothing" as @A. Meshu has said.
We know this because God created man using the dust of the earth.
*bara* means to create something new that has not existed before.

You left out verse 1.
In the beginning, God **created** the heavens and the earth.
This uses the word *bara*.
This is not a title as some think because the next verse starts with "and".
In the beginning God created the universe out of nothing.
We then see following v1, on days 1-6 that God did not create anything out of nothing.
It was all there from v1.

How long ago was that? The Bible doesn't say. It was in the beginning.

> **Day 1: Neither עשה nor ברא is used in describing creation of the light, but instead we have yehi owr wa-yehi owr ('Light shalt exist.' And light existed.)**

God didn't create or make light here because light already existed.

God had created it in v1 as part of the universe.

How can God create a universe without light?

Are we to believe that God created water, fire, heat, sound, and all the elements in v1, but not light?

v2 says darkness was upon the face of the deep.

This implies there was light elsewhere in the universe.

It is like if I said, there was darkness over my whole neighborhood.

That implies that outside my neighborhood somewhere, there was light.

If the entire universe was dark, why would God say, Darkness was on the face of the deep?

When God said, let there be light, He brought light to the earth.

This was when the first of the 7 days began.

This was 6,000 - 8,000 years ago.

I understand that most Christians think the first of the 7 days began with v1.

The text does not say when this day began.

But it tells us when the this and all the days ended.

They all ended at the morning of the next day

> > Gen 1:5 And God called the light Day, and the darkness he called Night. And there was evening, and there was morning -- one day.

H.C. Leupold says it better than I could:

> > "Then came evening, then came morning - the first day." To try to make this mean that the day began with evening, as days did according to the later Jewish reckoning (Lev 23:32), fails utterly, because verse 5 reports the conclusion of this day's work not its beginning. - H. C. Leupold

-

> **Day 2: עשה is used to describe creation of the firmament**

God made the firmament around the earth. God had already created firmaments in v1, so God was not creating something that never existed before.

Now He made one for the earth.

The firmament is the earth's atmosphere which keeps the clouds separated from the earth, so we can see.

The firmament of **the** heavens, (definite article) into which God placed the stars on the 4th day, is our galaxy, which God created when He created **the heavens** in v1.

> > I never thought of the firmament being the galaxy before, but I think it makes more sense than any other interpretation I've ever heard! - Pascal's Wager

Thanks! I say that because God set the stars in the firmament.

> **Day 3: Neither verb is used for God's creation of plants, but instead the earth "sprouts" (דשא) the vegetation. The verb עשה, however, is used to describe the tree "bearing" fruit (perhaps, in its own way, "creating" fruit?)**

I think the plant seeds were already left there from a previous creation on the earth that got destroyed between v1 and v2.

> **Day 4: עשה is used to describe creation of the luminaries**

God had already created the heavens in v1. That includes the stars.

Here God made the stars in our galaxy.

He uses the verb "made" because stars already had been created in v1, so God was not creating something that never existed before.

There were stars in other galaxies, but not in our galaxy.

All the stars visible to the naked eye are in our galaxy. The closest galaxy to our own, Andromeda, looks like 1 star.

> Day 5: ברא is used to describe creation of the sea-animals and sky-animals

These are new creatures, so God created them.

> Day 6: עשה is used to describe creation of the land-animals. עשה is also used when God says, "Let us create man in our image." But then, we have ברא used 3 times when God says "So God created man in his own image, in the image of God created he him; male and female created he them."

Man was something new that never existed before.

> From what you wrote, it sounds like ברא is used when God makes something for the first time ever and עשה is used when he makes something that has already been made before. – Pascal's Wager

Yes, and this is illustrated by the verse that summarizes all God's creation work in chapter 1:

> Genesis 2:3 And God blessed the seventh day, and hallowed it, because that on it he rested from all his work which God created for making.

"created for making" is what the Hebrew literally says. Or it could be translated "created [in order] to make".

Comment: I think the Bible is a great commentator on the Bible. *“By faith we understand that the universe was created by the word of God, so that what is seen was not made out of things that are **visible**.”
‭‭Hebrews‬ ‭11:3‬* I appreciate what you had to say but it feels so forced reading it, that its hard not to think you are experiencing cognitive dissonance. As an example, you said, light being made in v1 because v2 speaks of darkness but Isaiah 45:7 says that God יוצר darkness. Darkness is not the absence of light. Darkness has to be יצר. Now I’m convinced that v1 is part of day 1.

Comment: Also you are introducing extrabiblical concepts like galaxies. They don’t exist in the Bible but you smuggled them in. If the Bible says God made two lights, not one light and one reflector it could have said it. And if it wanted to say the stars became visible on the fourth day it could have said it but fact is that it says they were made ויעשׂ. It’s not a good idea to add to Scripture. Let Scripture explain itself.

Comment: @Autodidact, thank you for your truly helpful comments. I don't appreciate your name-calling though. I can see from your attitude toward the Word that you are a serious Christian. So I just leave that with you to consider.
I added more about why light was created in v1, and clarified what I meant by "God made the stars" on the 4th day. I agree with you: That means that God actually made them, not that He made them visible.
Also, fyi, your Hebrew came out backward in your upper comment, but is correct in your lower comment.

Comment: please help me identify the name calling you speak of, it’s difficult to apologize for something I can’t see I committed, especially since I avoid ad hominems as they don’t help my case and are a distraction. Also the Hebrew, I’ve given up trying to fix it, I don’t know why it happens or how to fix it. But thank you. I’ll re read your post and see if it makes different sense than previously.

Comment: @Autodidact - cognitive dissonance. thanks!

Comment: I can see that it might come across as offensive to some but it’s not name calling ...and how else am I to convey the same idea that you are mixing two conflicting statements and still trying to make sense of both? I’ve experienced cognitive dissonance many times, and it usually helps if someone else identifies it for me because it’s not always obvious to me. Certainly it was not name calling or intended to degrade or belittle. *anxiety that results from simultaneously holding contradictory or otherwise incompatible attitudes, beliefs, or the like*

Comment: I re read your post and I know you hate the two words I used but when you invoke secular gnostic and atheistic “knowledge” or so called science to describe Biblical cosmology you are imposing an extrabiblical model onto the Biblical text. And I abhor such reasoning! Here is my downvoted response on Biblical Cosmology. BTW there is zero evidence of galaxies. All you have is artist rendition. If you looked at the actual photo you couldn’t say it contains any stars because it’s so blurry. https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/38447/sky-and-land-vs-heaven-and-earth-in-gen-11/39063#39063

Comment: Like you, I believe the Bible interprets the Bible. Where we differ is that I believe in reconciling the Bible with facts. I believe we have to decide what parts of science are proven and which are not. For example, it is a fact that there is a meat-eating animal called a lion. There is no evidence of there ever being a plant-eating lion or of any macro evolution. Yet a lot of Christians (not Jews) believe that God created the lion to be a plant eater and it evolved into a carnivore after the fall. One possibly may think that from the Bible only, but not when you look at science also.

Comment: that’s funny you mention lions. The facts you speak of are based on the teeth of the lion supposedly adapted to eating meat. Except for the fact that bears have a similar teeth design to a lion and are mostly herbivores most of the time. I would challenge every single one of your facts and even if you were to prove those to be true it would not validate the Bible but it would invalidate it. For instance plants were created before the sun. Unless it was 24 hours from when plants were created to when the sun was created plants don’t exist in darkness and freezing conditions let alone evolve

Comment: Lion's teeth and digestive system is for meat. Before God made the sun, God had a different way of illuminating the earth. That is why God had to say Let there be light, before He told the plants to grow.

Comment: supposing in the ~6950 years since Creation or less from the flood, the lion became exclusively carnivore, that doesn’t deny the Bible. I believe in macro evolution. Also you can’t prove what the digestive tract of the lion was several thousands of years ago. You can only speculate. Also you don’t know what that light was, it might have been the entire electro magnetic spectrum for all we know. Fact is you would have to admit you are speculating.

Comment: Sure, it's speculation. But why insist that the lion was originally a plant eater, when there are other ways to understand the Bible and still be faithful to the literal text.
Thanks for the link to the other discussion. Looks interesting. I will read it.

Comment: because God says that in the day that Adam will eat he would surely die and Romans 8 says that all of nature was subjected to futility and corruption which is understood to mean death included. Hence death of higher life forms (with souls/nephesh) was not in the garden prior to the fall and lions therefore could not have feasted on meat in the garden. That’s the implication. So what’s the other explanation?

Comment: That's a decent argument. One I haven't heard. The bondage to vanity in Rom 8 is fear of death & suffering for humans. I don't see animals as being slaves to that fear. The bondage of corruption does not necessarily mean that all animals were supposed to live forever. Don't all animals have souls?

Comment: “For the **creation was subjected to futility**, not willingly, but because of Him who subjected it in hope; because the **creation itself also will be delivered from the bondage of corruption** into the glorious liberty of the children of God.”
‭‭Romans‬ ‭8:20-21‬ so animals were subjected to futility too. as for whether all animals have souls, I’m not familiar with all in the Hebrew text but certainly the higher organisms possibly limited to those with blood not insects but I’m not dogmatic in this point about the nephesh. Plants don’t have a nephesh.

Comment: +1 I never thought of the firmament being the galaxy before, but I think it makes more sense than any other interpretation I've ever heard! From what you wrote, it sounds like ברא is used when God makes something for the first time ever and עשה is used when he makes something that has already been made before.

Comment: @Pascal's Wager, I added your comments to my answer, and commented further on them.

Comment: @Pascal'sWager please explain how that makes any sense at all to you. The firmament is a galaxy? Are you aware that is secular science a galaxy is a massive collection of stars primarily? Stars are made on day four. How does that make any sense? And v7 speaks of waters above the expanse. Where did this water in this supposed galaxy go? This is entirely incongruent and yet it makes sense, how? Please explain.

Comment: @Autodidact I'm not saying that I'm 100% convinced that the firmament is a galaxy, but I do think that it is consistent with the text. God *could* have made the sun and moon on day 4 but the other stars earlier, maybe on day 1. *Maybe* "he made the stars also" has a pluperfect meaning. But I agree that this seems a little far fetched and isn't the first conclusion one would arrive at while reading the text, although sometimes the counterintuitive interpretation is the correct interpretation. (i.e. "Why do you call me good? No one is good but God?") But your objection is very good! +1

Comment: Autodidact is right, that the firmament on Day 2 cannot be our galaxy. It has to be the atmosphere. 
I think the firmament of **the** heavens (definite article) into which God placed the stars on day 4 - that is our galaxy. I will revise my post

Answer (score 0):

Can't find related articles - yet i'm sure someone said that before me in the past 2000 years:

In biblical Hebrew, whn we read ברא it means to create from nothing, and when we read עשה it means to create something from something.

So as for your question: both water on the ground and water on the sky are made from the same thing - water. Since Genesis won't say that God created the water, the writer use עשה root to say that God made the sky and the sea. How? He "just" seperate the water...

Comment: This verse does not describe the creation of sky and sea. It describes the creation of a firmament, which can hold up the pre-exisisting waters.

Comment: on the second day God separate the pre existing water and made with (some of) them the firmament.

Comment: @A.Meshu If your theory is correct, that ברא means creation from nothing and עשה means creation from something, why would ברא be used for the sea-creatures and the fowls but עשה be used for the land animals?

Comment: I guess it's like in evolution - all life started from sea. So God create the sea creatures and after a "day" made the land animals from them.

Comment: @A.Meshu Interesting... But, if all life started from the sea, why is ברא applied to the creation of the fowls as well? Moreover, why is ברא used (albeit along with עשה) for the creation of man? Wasn't Adam made from the adamah(soil)? Or perhaps עשה refers to the creation of Adam's body (from the adamah) while ברא refers to the creation of his soul from nothing?

Comment: @Pascal'sWager well as Ben Maymon wrote: In order to really understand why (how) God actually act \ do something - you should be God himself.

Comment: . . . and if either of you are actually God, be sure to write a book about it. Also, please make it short and at a level that ordinary people can understand. ;-)

Comment: Personally, I don't see any instance in Genesis 1 where God creates anything "ex nihilo". Everything is made from something else. I think you would have to produce an example. Thanks.